# How to update div when on select change in jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a form with a select field and a div i wish to update with a value depending on what the user selects.

Example:

```
<select name="mysel" id="msel">
    <option value="test1">Test1</option>
    <option value="test2">Test2</option>
    <option value="test3">Test3</option>
</select>

<div id="myresult"></div>
```

I would like the div to update with "This is test 2 and other info" if the user selects test2 and so on.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to escape your HTML. It's getting eaten by SO.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try something like that :

```
<select id="choose">
    <option value="test1">Test1</option>
    <option value="test2">Test2</option>
    <option value="test3">Test3</option>
</select>
<div id="update"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#choose').change(function(event) {
        $('#update').html('This is ' + $('#choose').val() + ' and other info');
    }); 
</script>
```

---

If you want to make it with AJAX, change the javascript function to something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#choose').change(function(event) {
        $.post('info.php', { selected: $('#choose').val() },
            function(data) {
                $('#update').html(data);
            }
        );            
    });
</script>
```

And in your info.php, you'll have something like:

```
<?php

    $selected = isset($_POST['selected']) ? $_POST['selected'] : 'nothing';
    echo("This is $selected and other info");
```

Comment: Thank you both for the great replies, i would would like for it to send the value of the select to a php file via ajax, in that way i can use a switch to send back data to the div. The php part i can do but executing the ajax call is where I am lost. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Here you go, but please update (by adding at the bottom) the original question so people looking for a similar answer can benefit from it.

Answer (score 3):

The general idea:

```
$(function() {
   $("#msel").change(function(){
      $("#myresult").html("This is " + $("#msel").val() + " and other info");
   });
});
```

With more specifics I can do better. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is the simplest way I've found do it (from [this](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=194923) handy forum)

```
<!-- the select -->
<select id="thechoices">
    <option value="box1">Box 1</option>
    <option value="box2">Box 2</option>
    <option value="box3">Box 3</option>
</select>

<!-- the DIVs -->
<div id="boxes">
    <div id="box1"><p>Box 1 stuff...</p></div>
    <div id="box2"><p>Box 2 stuff...</p></div>
    <div id="box3"><p>Box 3 stuff...</p></div>
</div>

<!-- the jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#thechoices").change(function(){
    $("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
});

$("#thechoices").change();

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

### on document ready

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#choose').change(function(event) {    
          $.post(
           'info.php',
            $(this).serialize(),
            function(data){
              $("#update").html(data)
            }
          );
          return false;   
        });   
    });
```

### on ajaxComplete

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
        $('#choose').change(function(event) {    
          $.post(
           'info.php',
            $(this).serialize(),
            function(data){
              $("#update").html(data)
            }
          );
          return false;   
        });   
    });
```