# Update div with jQuery upon entry of data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with four text input elements.  Every time one of them is updated, I want the sum of the four text input boxes to be displayed in a div below without the user pushing a button.  Here's what I have so far (I got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628508/how-to-update-div-when-on-select-change-in-jquery) [does this only work with select?]):

```
var getSum = function() {
    var email = $('#emailDown').val();
    var internet = $('#internetDown').val();
    var server = $('#serverDown').val();
    var desktop = $('#pcDown').val();
    //TODO:Check for integers (not needed with sliders)
    var sum = email + internet + server + desktop;
    $('totalHoursDown').html(sum);
}
$('#emailDown').change(getSum(event));
$('#internetDown').change(getSum(event));
$('#serverDown').change(getSum(event));
$('#pcDown').change(getSum(event));
```

Currently, it's not updating.  (Don't worry about validating).  I'm new to PHP, so I'm not sure if I should be using it in this instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a `#` or `.` in your selector, depending on if `totalHoursDown` is a class or an ID:

```
$('totalHoursDown').html(sum);

// Should be this if ID
$('#totalHoursDown').html(sum);
// or this if class
$('.totalHoursDown').html(sum);
```

**Update:**

I modified the code by **jmar777** a bit to make it work. Try this instead:

```
$(function(){
    var $fields = $('#emailDown, #internetDown, #serverDown, #pcDown'),
    $totalHoursDown = $('#totalHoursDown');
    $fields.change(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $fields.each(function() 
                 { 
                     var val = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
                     sum += (isNaN(val)) ? 0 : val; 
                 });
        $totalHoursDown.html(sum);
    });
});
```

​Here is a working fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/mSqtD/

Comment: I don't get any errors using either my code or the code @jmar777 used.  (On Chrome's Javascript console)

Comment: Very nice!  You even got some validation in.  Thanks for making my day headache-free.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var $fields = $('#emailDown, #internetDown, #serverDown, #pcDown'),
    $totalHoursDown = $('#totalHoursDown');
$fields.change(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $fields.each(function() { sum += $(this).val(); });
    $totalHoursDown.html(sum);
});
```

Also, in your example, you had `$('totalHoursDown').html(sum);`, which I'm assuming was intended to be an ID selector (i.e., `$('#totalHoursDown').html(sum);`.