# changing div according to the list value using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to change the width and height of a div by selecting the values from the list

```
<select id="selectSize">
<option selected>Please Select</option>
<option>45x40</option>
<option>50x20</option>
<option>50x30</option>
<option>63x30</option>
<option>75x40</option>
</select>
<div id="sizeBox"></div>
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with? You don't seem to have any code written at all.

Comment: You have the same **ID** for the `select` and `div`. **ID** must be unique.

Comment: You will find what you need here in jquery, too.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628508/how-to-update-div-when-on-select-change-in-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Jdbyk/1/

HTML

```
<select onchange="Change()" id="sizeSel">
<option selected>Please Select</option>
<option>HP to decide</option>
<option value="45x40">45x40</option>
<option value="50x20">50x20</option>
<option value="50x30">50x30</option>
<option value="63x30">63x30</option>
<option value="75x40">75x40</option>
</select>
<div style="border:1px solid red;" id="sizeBox"></div>
```

JQUERY

```
function Change()
{
    var boxsize = $('#sizeSel').val();
    var strs = boxsize.split("x");

    $('#sizeBox').width(strs[0]);
    $('#sizeBox').height(strs[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try my answer:

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("change", "#sizeBoxSelect", function () {
        var $this = $('select#sizeBoxSelect option:selected'),
            iWidth = parseInt($this.val().split(",")[0]),
            iHeight = parseInt($this.val().split(",")[1]);

        $("#sizeBox").width(iWidth).height(iHeight);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dkb8G/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    $('#sizeSel').on('change',function(){
        var dim = $(this).val();
        var wh= dim.split("x");
        $('#sizeBox').css({'width':wh[0]+'px','height':wh[1]+'px'});
    });
});
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/hFg7d/

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7wyxG/2/) you have an approach with Jquery.

HTML:

```
<select id="selectBox">
<option selected>Please Select</option>
<option>HP to decide</option>
<option>45x40</option>
<option>50x20</option>
<option>50x30</option>
<option>63x30</option>
<option>75x40</option>
</select>
<div id="sizeBox"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#selectBox').change(function() {
    $("option:selected", this).each(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var height = value.split('x')[0];
        var width = value.split('x')[1];
        $('#sizeBox').css("width", width);
        $('#sizeBox').css("height", height);
    });
});
```

Comment: Does using `each` make sense here?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to call the **change()** event on the listbox element and change the length and width of the target element.here is the working example

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/B4xbF/)

**JS**

```
$('#sizeBox').on('change', function () {
// alert( $(this).html());
var $this = $('Select option:selected');
var length = $this.attr("lt");
var height = $this.attr("ht");
alert(length + ":" + height);
$('#tarDiv').width(height);
$('#tarDiv').height(length);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="sizeBox">
<option selected>Please Select</option>
<option>HP to decide</option>
<option lt="45" ht="40">45x40</option>
<option lt="50" ht="20">50x20</option>
<option lt="50" ht="30">50x30</option>
<option lt="63" ht="30">63x30</option>
<option lt="75" ht="40">75x40</option>
</select>
<div id="tarDiv" class="colorME" style="background-color:green;padding-top:50px;width:100px;height:100px;overflow:auto;">Change ME!!!</div>
```